# Indices of two numbers equal to a target value

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sum

I was trying to solve this problem and I got stuck at the end. This function takes a list consisting of integers and a target value.The **indices** of any **two** sum of integers which is equal to the target value should be returned.   For Eg: - ([1,2,3],4) should return [0,2] because 3+1=4. My Approach: -

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
def indices(numbers,target):
    comb_nos = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(numbers, 2)]
    print(comb_nos)
    result =np.sum(comb_nos,1)
    print(result)
indices([2,2,3],4)
```

I managed to get all combinations of the integers in a set of 2(using the itertools module) and use the numpy library to sum it up along an axis of 1. I can't seem to figure out a way to print the indices.
The Combination of integers are `[[2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3]]` and the sum of those individual lists correspondingly are `[4 5 5]`. I want to print the indices of 4(Which is the target value)

There are few hints out there but since I have reached almost the ending,I want to know how I could have done it my way.I would appreciate it if anyone could help me solve this.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what problem you have going forward? Would you know how to proceed if you knew how to get the index for each number? How about having a pair of ``index, value`` for each number? Are you aware of ``enumerate``? Is there a reason why you are using numpy for this?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sure. Assuming there is only one combination in the list of integers which when added equals to the target value. I need to print out the indices of those numbers. suppose the input to the function is `indices([1234,5678,9012],14690) `. It should return the indices of those integers which when added is equal to 14690. In this case,the indices would be [1,2]. Since 5678+9012=14690.  I am open to other solutions as well.

Comment: @AshwinNeogi if you know there is only going to be one combination that equals to target, you probably can do faster than checking all combinations. But if you are not worried as much about performance and want a working code, my post should get you to the answer.

Comment: @Ehsan  Thanks for the solution! I did try your code and up-voted it yesterday. Just didn't know how to accept the answer:) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain python solution:

```
def indices(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
            if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                return [i,j]
            else:
                return "no pair in nums list sums to target"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without loop by calculating all combinations of pairwise summation of elements using numpy broadcasting and then searching for target using `np.argwhere` (if your arrays are too large, using itertools might be slightly more efficient as this one calculates every combination twice, however it is faster in the calculations itself):

```
def indices(numbers,target):
  idx = np.argwhere((numbers.T[:,None]+numbers.T)==target)
  return (idx[idx[:,0]<idx[:,1]])
print(indices(np.array([2,2,3]),4))
```

And if you want to use itertools, you can do it this way:

```
def indices(numbers,target):
  idx = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(len(numbers)),2)))
  return idx[np.flatnonzero(numbers[np.r_[idx]].sum(1) == target)]
print(indices(np.array([2,2,3]),4))
```

output:

```
[[0 1]]
```

**EDIT**: explanation:
`numbers.T[:,None]+numbers.T` creates a matrix of summations of all pairwise combinations of `numbers`. In other words, its `[i,j]`-th element is `numbers[i]+numbers[j]`. `np.argwhere` finds which of those are equal to `target`.

`idx[:,0]<idx[:,1]` is a condition to filter upper triangle of matrix, since lower triangle of matrix is the same pairwise combinations of numbers as upper triangle (e.g. `[0,1]` vs. `[1,0]`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combinations()` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import combinations


def indices(numbers, target):

    return [[f[0] for f in s] for s in combinations(enumerate(numbers),2)if sum([f[1] for f in s])==target]

print(indices([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2],6))
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) { 
        
        int[] ans = new int[2];
       
       for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++)
            {
                if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target)
                {
                    ans[0]=i;
                    ans[1]=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    return ans;
        
        
    }
        
        public static void main(String args[]){ 
            
            Solution sol = new Solution();
            int[] arr = {1,0,2,4,5};
           int[] ans = sol.twoSum(arr, 7);
           
                 
           for (int i=0;i<ans.length;i++) {
              
               System.out.println(ans[i]);
             
               
           }
            
                      
        
    }
   
}
```